# ActiveRecord::InvalidForeignKey: PG::ForeignKeyViolation How can i get this relationshop objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations, ruby-on-rails-5.1

As i mentioned on the question..

I know this error and i know how associations work

In my case i have `ProductRepository` model which belongs_to :`category`

So of course when i'm trying to delete this category which this ProductRepository object belongs to i should get this error and it's totally fine and i know how to handle this exception

Now let's say that i have a many models which referring to categories like
Product, ProductRepositoy, Post, etc...

**My question** **here**, how can i get a list of this objects which belongs to categories, or even get a class name array or whatever

So when i handle this exception i can send a message to ask the user to check and delete the following before deleting this category ?

**Example:**
Once user delete category... if it has any items which belongs to it
he should get a message saying Please check the following (*Posts, Products, etc..*)

For who is going to answer, all i need is how to get this objects or even class names only

And i can do the rest

Thanks in advance :)

Here is the file, after removing what isn't necessary for the question

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :brands, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :products, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

product_respository.rb

```
class ProductRepository < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  has_many :unity_folders, as: :product, dependent: :destroy

  validates :name, :price, :barcode, presence: true
  validates :barcode, uniqueness: true
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :brand
  belongs_to :organization
  has_many :unity_folders, as: :product, dependent: :destroy
  has_one :product3d
  belongs_to :shop
end
```

Comment: Could you please attach your product, category and ProductCategory Models?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. It's really hard to debug/help with a verbal description of your code... as the commenter above said - can you please edit your question and add relevant snippets of your actual code. Then we can see for ourselves how your code is structured and can then suggest improvements to solve your problem. Thanks :)

Comment: I have attached the requested models, and let's say when i delete the category now i want to know the objects which are associated with it, or at least the class name of this objects, so i can tell the user, please check and delete the products repositories before being able to remove the category, of course i need this on the exception handling, as for now all i did is rescuing this exception with a flash which says there are items associated with the object you're trying to delete, please make sure you deleted them first, and i can't even tell him what to check and what to delete, thanks :)